# IE11 and rendering issues

Tags: rendering, internet-explorer-11

The page http://www.komplett.no/k/kc.aspx?bn=10149 triggers something strange in IE which causes the browser to use 100% CPU and render the page very slow and eventually hangs. If you try to open Developer Tools (F12) the browser stops completely. Other category pages on the site is very slow, but product pages and campaign pages works just fine. There has to be a bug in IE11, but I want to know what triggers it.

If you turn off hardware acceleration it works just fine!

This occurs in both v11.0.9 and v11.0.2

Does anyone see what could cause this?

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem, but I' running pretty vanilla Intel HD Graphics 4000 video. Is it really IE having the 100% CPU according to task manager? Since it's associated with hw acceleration it might be a video driver issue.

Comment: It's the iexplore.exe process that is using 100% on one CPU. There's  a lot of customers complaining about this, so there has to be a fault not only targeting a specific video driver, but several. The problem also come and goes on my machine, so it looks like it's have something to do with the state iexplore is in.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. If you set the absolute positioned elements inside the product box to a random given z-index, IE is no longer struggling to render the page. For me, it makes no sense, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of clash of the jquery, it happens with me also and finally i change it to Jquery.